# checkpointing DataFrames in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, checkpointing

I am looping over a number of csv data files using R/spark.  About 1% of each file must be retained (filtered based on certain criteria) and merged with the next data file (I have used `union`/`rbind`).  However, as the loop runs, the lineage of the data gets longer and longer as spark remembers all the previous datasets and `filter()`-s.

Is there a way to do checkpointing in spark R API?  I have learned that spark 2.1 has checkpointing for DataFrames but this seems not to be made available from R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got the same issue with Scala/GraphX on a quite large graph (few billions of data) and the search for connected components .

I'm not sure what is available in R for your specific version, but a usual workaround is to break the lineage by "saving" the data then reloading it. In our case, we break the lineage every 15 iterations:

```
def refreshGraph[VD: ClassTag, ED: ClassTag](g: Graph[VD, ED], checkpointDir: String, iterationCount: Int, numPartitions: Int): Graph[VD, ED] = {
    val path = checkpointDir + "/iter-" + iterationCount
    saveGraph(g, path)
    g.unpersist()
    loadGraph(path, numPartitions)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see you use different file at each loop.  I tried it earlier with the same file so it did not work.  I will test and accept your answer if it works for me.

Comment: It seems to be working now :-)  Although I run into another bottleneck :-(

Comment: You can either edit your first question or link to your new issue

Answer (score 0):

An incomplete solution/workaround is to `collect()` your dataframe into an R object, and later re-parallelize by `createDataFrame()`.  This works well for small data but for larger datasets it become too slow and complains about too large tasks.